# Incorrect prices in shopping cart via SOAP API v2

Tags: magento-1.7, price, api, shopping-cart, totals

Store have configurable product, which costs 750 ("base version"), via API I want to buy configured product, which costs 1500. When I just try to get `shoppingCartTotals()`, I get right prices (with right tax), but when I try to get shipping and payment methods - prices changing.

Here is code:

```
<?php

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('ApiUser', 'ApiKey');

$quoteId = $proxy->shoppingCartCreate( $sessionId, 3 );

/*$customerData = array(
    "firstname" => "-",
    "lastname" => "-",
    "email" => "guest@example.com",
    "mode" => "guest",
    "website_id" => "0"
);*/

//$proxy->shoppingCartCustomerSet($sessionId, $quoteId, $customerData);

$proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses($sessionId, $quoteId, array(array(
    'mode' => 'billing',
    'firstname' => '-',
    'lastname' => '-',
    'street' => '-',
    'city' => '-',
    'region' => '-',
    'postcode' => '-',
    'country_id' => 'UK',
    'telephone' => '-',
    'is_default_billing' => 1
)));

$proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd(
    $sessionId,
    $quoteId,
    array(
        array(
            'sku' => '111111',
            'qty' => '1',
            'options' => array(
                array(
                    "key" => 111,
                    "value" => 1212,
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
    3 //storeId

);
//Uncomment following lines for price changing
//$result_payment = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $quoteId, array('method' => 'checkmo'), 3);
//$result_shipping = $proxy->shoppingCartShippingMethod($sessionId, $quoteId, 'freeshipping_freeshipping', 3);
//echo var_dump(array('shoppingCartPaymentMethod' => $result_payment,'shoppingCartShippingMethod' => $result_shipping)); 

//$result = $proxy->shoppingCartInfo($sessionId, $quoteId, 3);
//var_dump($result);

$result = $proxy->shoppingCartTotals($sessionId, $quoteId, 3);
var_dump($result);
```

And here is results:

1. Without shipping and payment methods:

   ```
     array(3) {
     [0]=>
     object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(8) "Subtotal"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(1500)
     }
     [1]=>
     object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(3) "Tax"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(300)
     }
     [2]=>
     object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(11) "Grand Total"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(1500)
     }
   }
   ```
2. With shipping and payment methods:

   ```
     array(2) {
     ["shoppingCartPaymentMethod"]=>
     bool(true)
     ["shoppingCartShippingMethod"]=>
     bool(true)
   }
   array(4) {
     [0]=>
     object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(8) "Subtotal"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(780)
     }
     [1]=>
     object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(3) "Tax"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(156)
     }
     [2]=>
     object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(40) "Shipping & Handling (Fri frakt - Gratis)"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(0)
     }
     [3]=>
     object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
       ["title"]=>
       string(11) "Grand Total"
       ["amount"]=>
       float(780)
     }
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($sessionId, $quoteId, array(
    'po_number' => null,
    'method' => 'checkmo',
    'cc_cid' => null,
    'cc_owner' => null,
    'cc_number' => null,
    'cc_type' => null,
    'cc_exp_year' => null,
    'cc_exp_month' => null), 
3);
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartPayment/cart_payment.method.html